# Como respetar saltos de lineas de texto copiado al portapapeles

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buen día, tengo un pequeño código que consigue copiar un texto que esta dentro de un webView el cual carga una página web. El problema es que no consigo que al extraer el texto del portapapeles este no respeta los saltos de líneas.

```
final ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                ClipData clipData = clipboard.getPrimaryClip();

                ClipData.Item item = null;
                if (clipData != null) {
                    item = clipData.getItemAt(0);
                    if (!mPreviousText[0].equals(item.getText().toString())){

                        mPreviousText[0] = item.getText().toString();
                        myEditText.setText(mPreviousText[0]);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

suponiendo que el texto que copie es el siguiente:

"Una palabra del traductor a sus amigos

Yo ofrezco

desnudas, vírgenes, intactas y sencillas."

lo que me devuelve sería:

"Una palabra del traductor a sus amigos Yo ofrezco desnudas, vírgenes, intactas y sencillas."

Y no se a que se deba, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: El ejemplo es muy poco feliz.

Answer (score 0):

Sabiendo que estas extrayendo el texto desde un WebView, seguramente los saltos de linea están representados como `<br>`

```
   "Una palabra del traductor a sus amigos
    <br>
    Yo ofrezco
    <br>
    desnudas, vírgenes, intactas y sencillas."
```

Por lo tanto te sugiero realizar un reemplazo de los saltos de linea en html por `\n` usando el método `.replace()`:

```
.replace("<br>","\n")
```

Esta sería la forma de realizarlo en tu código:

```
item.getText().toString().replace("<br>","\n")
```